# Extend one module from angular app in a sub app

Tags: angular

I am developing a big angular application.
The basic application contains only login form and principal menu.
I would like to implement 2 plugins/modules to extend functionality of the main application.
If I include Plugin1, I see a new item in menu and navigating from it I can see all Plugin1's views. Same thing with Plugin2 and other plugins..
Another thing.. Plugin enabled/disabled have to depend from a configuration in json.

How can I develop this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the needed plugins as modules for the application and load that module using lazy loading. What lazy loading does is it only loads the module when you need it. and you can display the links to modules for lazy loading in the navigation bar by getting the data from the configurations file and by the use of structural directives, that is `ngIf` . to achieve the above requirements.

for more information on lazy loading visit the official documentation it has a nice example in it.

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules